# NUnit TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, nunit, testcasesource

I'm having a go with the TestCaseSource attribute. One problem: when the sourceName string is invalid, the test just gets ignored instead of failing. This would be really bad if the source method gets renamed, the sourceName string doesn't get updated, and then you lose the coverage that the test provided. Is there a way to change the behaviour of NUnit, so that the test fails if the sourceName is invalid?

Comment: At [tag:nunit] `2.5.10` I get following exception, where TestCaseSource has invalid name: `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.` What is your test runner: nunit, resharper, icarus?

Comment: Hi, using ReSharper and NUnit in TC: ReSharper 6.1, ReSharper 7.0.97.60, TC with NUnit 2.5.3 and TC with NUnit 2.6.0. Get an exception thrown in the TestFixture (System.Exception: Unable to locate SomeClass.SomeMethodThatDoesntExist), but the "failing" tests get ignored

Comment: Yes, you are right. When run all test at once test with incorrect `TestCaseSource` are Ingored with `System.Exception : Unable to locate XXX`. May be someone knows solution for this.

Comment: C# 6 `nameof` to the rescue. I much prefer `nameof` to `typeof` for this.

Answer (score 7):

This is resolved in NUnit 2.6.2. There is a new constructor for the attribute that takes a `Type` (which must implement `IEnumerable`); it "is recommended for use in preference to other forms because it doesn't use a string to specify the data source and is therefore more easily refactored." (From the [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.2).)

This does require that your test runner supports the latest NUnit.

A very basic example (see the above documentation link for more details):

```cs
public class TestDataProvider : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new List<int>{ 2, 4, 6 }.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataProvider))]
    public void TestOne(int number)
    {
        Assert.That(number % 2, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've looked how it work internally in NUnit.
They just throws exception if particular source does not exists:

```
MemberInfo[] members = providerType.GetMember(
 providerName,
 MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Method | MemberTypes.Property,
 BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

if (members.Length == 0)
 throw new Exception(string.Format(
  "Unable to locate {0}.{1}", providerType.FullName, providerName));
```

Later they catch it and mark particular `ParameterSet` (class which wraps test case source) as `RunState.NotRunnable` which will later be handled as Ignored test.

So, there is probably no way to change this behavior without changing NUnit code - which is btw available for download. You can also try to contact with NUnit team or just treat ignored test in the same way as failing ones:)

Answer (score 3):

How about using **nameof** feature introduced in C#6

```
public static class TestCasesData 
{ 
  public static string[] TestStringsData() 
  {
       return new string[] {"TEST1", "TEST2"};
  }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{
     [Test]
     [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCasesData), nameof(TestCasesData.TestStringsData))]
     public void TestCase1(...)
     {
     }
}
```